# dynamic linking vs loading the library at runtime

Tags: compilation, linker, shared-libraries

I'm reading a Mastering Embedded Linux Programming book. Came across the following paragraph:

```
libjpeg.a: This is the library archive used for static linking
libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.8.0.2: This is a symbolic link, used for dynamic linking
libjpeg.so.8 -> libjpeg.so.8.0.2: This is a symbolic link, used when loading the library at runtime
libjpeg.so.8.0.2: This is the actual shared library, used at both compile time and runtime
```

What is the difference between `dynamic linking` and `loading the library at runtime`?

Answer (score 0):

> Came across the following paragraph

The book author is likely confused.

There is no *fundamental* reason to have anything other than `libjpeg.so`, which is a shared library that is usable both for linking *and* runtime loading.

The reason for all the `.so.8.0.2` naming and symlinking is external library versioning, described e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54813/chapter5-5.html#scrolltoc).

External versioning is not necessary at all on GNU systems that support [symbol versioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning).

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is meant by "external library versioning"? I did read the article you pointed me to, but I'm not very clear about the "external library" term. Are there non-external libraries, i.e. internal ones? If there are then what is the difference between external and internal library? If there aren't then why do they call it an "external library"?

Comment: @flashburn There is no such thing as "external library"; it's the *version* that is external (meaning you have several versions of the same library that co-exist on a single machine, as different files). All of this is fairly advanced, you don't *need* to understand this yet.